# Windows 10 Update breaks EV code signing certificate

Tags: certificate, windows-10, outlook-addin, code-signing, symantec

Last night my machine did a Windows 10 update. I didn't think much of it at the time, except that it seemed to take longer than usual.  This morning when I did a build of our product, an Outlook 2013 Add-In, Windows 10 refused to recognize our Symantec Class 3 Extended Validation Code Signing Certificate.  This is a USB Token-based certificate, without which you cannot install our Add-In into Outlook.

To verify the problem was with the Windows 10 update I tried an install with another machine that did not go through the update and it installed without any problem.

Has anyone else experienced similar behavior with the latest Windows 10 update?  Does anyone have a suggested fix for the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have discovered that the fix is to un-install, and then re-install the Safenet Authentication Client software.  Once this is done the EV certificate can once again be bound correctly to the code and will be recognized by the updated version of Windows 10.